# get the length of a curve with integral

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, algebraic-curves

I need to get the length of a curve which equation is :

$$y= (4-x^\frac{2}{3})^\frac{3}{2}$$

I need to find the length using the method :

$$L=\int_a^b \sqrt{ 1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$$

So I started by evaluating dy/dx which gave me :

$$-\frac{\sqrt{4-x^\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

Then I integrated using the method stated before which gave me at end :

$$x\sqrt{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{x^\frac{2}{3}}\right)^\frac{3}{2}$$

Last step, I tried to evaluate the integral from 0 to 8 which is the domain of the curve... But I realised my integral was unsolvable for 0 So I guess I made a mistake somewhere...

What Am I missing here ?

**Solution**

My mistake was that I kept the minus sign even when elevating to 2.

The integral was actually easy to resolve without that minus sign...

$$L=\int_a^b \sqrt{ 1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$

$$= \int_a^b \sqrt{ 1 +\frac{4-x^\frac{2}{3}}{x^\frac{2}{3}} + 1}dx$$

$$= \int_a^b \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{x}}dx$$

$$= 2 \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}dx$$

$$= 3x^\frac{2}{3} + C$$

Now I need to evaluate from 0 to 8... Which equals to 12u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us simplify $1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$. From your correct expression for the derivative, we get 
$$1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=1+\frac{4-x^{2/3}}{x^{2/3}}.$$
Bring the expression on the right to the common denominator $x^{2/3}$. There is nice cancellation, and the problem collapses.

**Remarks:** $1.$ In principle there is an issue at $0$, since our integrand blows up there. But it is a convergent improper integral.

$2.$ There was some incorrect algebra in your calculation.

Comment: We are squaring the derivative. The minus sign disappears. (This is in response to a comment that disappeared.)

Comment: Yep, I just realized... Now my integral gives me 3x^(2/3) which won't cause any problem evaluating with 0 unless I made another mistake...

Comment: Yes, now the antiderivative is correct.  Typical arclength problem, the integrand "magically" simplifies.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit my post to show the steps to resolve... Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.